# Survival analysis with different size of failures

Tags: forecasting, survival

I have a dataset which includes both time to failure events as well as size/cost of failure. I am interested in estimating (preferably non-parametrically) the cumulative cost of failures as a function of time.

I am not familiar with this area but from my reading into survival analysis, it seems that it only looks at time to failures and treats all failures as identical. So if in my situation if all failures had the same sizes, I could have used the Kaplan-Meier or Nelson-Aalen estimator (correct?). Is there an analogous estimator which can also handle failures of different sizes/costs?